# Closing a ParcelFileDescriptor file descriptor after detaching

Tags: android, file-descriptor, parcelfiledescriptor

In Android I use the method [detachFd](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#detachFd()) from the [ParceFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor) to get a **file descriptor** that I pass to native code for usage. As the **file descriptor** is detached I close it in native code using **fdclose**.

Since it is detached, should I still [close](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#close()) the [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor) java instance?

Seems to me that I shouldn't, but I find that in older versions of Android such as Lollipop, StrictMode complains that the resource was not closed, probably because has no idea that it has been detached.

If it is required to **close** the **ParcelFileDescriptor** even when the file descriptor has been detached, are there any side effects to be aware of if closed while still using the detached one in native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard practice, like this：

```
try (ParcelFileDescriptor pFd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(path), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)) {
    int fd = pFd.detachFd();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Because "ParcelFileDescriptor" and "fd" have been separated, closing the object will not affect "fd".

```c
// native

close(fd)
```